# How to send backspace using sendmessage(C#) to cmd.exe

Tags: c#, stdin, cmd, sendmessage

I am trying to send keystrokes to cmd.exe that I launch from my app. In doing so, I am able to send all the keyboard characters, but if I try to send Backspace, it doesnt seem to take effect. The following is the code snippet to send message to cmd.exe:

```
SendMessage((int)shell.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYDOWN, ((int)e.KeyCode), 0);
SendMessage((int)shell.MainWindowHandle, WM_KEYUP, ((int)e.KeyCode), 0);
```

Any idea why this wouldnt work? What is the best way to send to the stdin of cmd.exe from a C# app?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You will have to P/Invoke [SendInput()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(VS.85).aspx) because Backspace is processed by the keyboard driver directly.

Answer (score 1):

`string msg = "Hello Cmd";`

`int i=0;`

`for (i=0; i < msg.Length ; i++)`

`SendMessage(cmdHwnd, WM_CHAR, (int)msg[i], 0);`

the above method helps you input any character in a string also CAPS and Space are considered.

The only problem is what I am facing is if u send message previously and it is still processing then a string having same character twice like "channel" then string entered is chanel and not channel.
I am currently finding a solution for this problem.

Murali can u share you code with me for KEYDOWN and KEYUP with KeyCode.

BR,

Rahul

Answer (score 0):

use the ascii code:
backspace --> OCT 0x10, char 'BS'

Comment: The problem with sendinput is that it requires the console app to be in the foreground. But I am actually keeping it hidden and capturing inputs and outputs to it. :(

Also e.KeyCode was 0x8 that matches with the ascii code for BS